# Foam knife one on Breville dual boiler?

Tags: espresso-machine, steamed-milk

Is there any method to install the foam knife one steam tip (such as [this one](https://www.espressoparts.com/sproline-foam-knife-1-steam-tip)) on the Breville BES920xl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, from some quick research, it looks like the Breville Dual Boiler has a steam arm that possesses a female thread where the steam tip is inserted *into* the steam arm.

However the Foam Knife 1 Steam Tip you linked looks to also possess a female thread which means that it cannot be fitted on to the Breville Dual Boiler without modifying the steam arm in some way or replacing the steam arm for another compatible one that has male threading.